# SQLAlchemy commit changes to object modified through __dict__

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, commit

I am developing a multiplayer game. When I use an object from inventory, it should update the user creature's stats with the values of the attributes of an object.

This is my code:

```
try:
    obj = self._get_obj_by_id(self.query['ObjectID']).first()

    # Get user's current creature
    cur_creature = self.user.get_current_creature()

    # Applying object attributes to user attributes
    for attribute in obj.attributes:
        cur_creature.__dict__[str(attribute.Name)] += attribute.Value

    dbObjs.session.commit()
except (KeyError, AttributeError) as err:
    self.query_failed(err)
```

Now, this doesn't commit things properly for some reason, so I tried:

```
cur_creature.Health  = 100
logging.warning(cur_creature.Health)
dbObjs.session.commit()
```

Which works, but is not very convenient (since I would need a big if statement to updated the different stats of the creature)

So I tried:

```
cur_creature.__dict__['Health'] = 100
logging.warning(cur_creature.Health)
dbObjs.session.commit()
```

I get `100` in logs, but no changes, so I tried:

```
cur_creature.__dict__['Health'] = 100
cur_creature.Health  = cur_creature.__dict__['Health']
logging.warning(cur_creature.Health)
dbObjs.session.commit()
```

Still '100' in logs, but no changes, so I tried:

```
cur_creature.__dict__['Health'] = 100
cur_creature.Health  = 100
logging.warning(cur_creature.Health)
dbObjs.session.commit()
```

Which still writes 100 in the logs, but doesn't commit changes to the database. 
Now, this is weird, since it only differ by the working version for the fact that it has this line on top:

```
cur_creature.__dict__['Health'] = 100
```

**Summary:** If I modify an attribute directly, commit works fine. Instead, if I modify an attribute through the class' dictionary, then, no matter how I modify it afterwards, it doesn't commit changes to the db.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE 1:

Also, this updates Health in the db, but not Hunger:

```
cur_creature.__dict__['Hunger'] = 0
cur_creature.Health  = 100
cur_creature.Hunger = 0
logging.warning(cur_creature.Health)
dbObjs.session.commit()
```

So just accessing the dictionary is not a problem for attributes in general, but modifying an attribute through the dictionary, prevents the changes to that attributes from being committed.

Update 2:

As a temporary fix, I've overridden the function `__set_item__(self)` in the class `Creatures`:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key == "Health":
       self.Health = value
    elif key == "Hunger":
       self.Hunger = value
```

So that the new code for 'use object' is:

```
try:
    obj = self._get_obj_by_id(self.query['ObjectID']).first()

    # Get user's current creature
    cur_creature = self.user.get_current_creature()

    # Applying object attributes to user attributes
    for attribute in obj.attributes:
        cur_creature[str(attribute.Name)] += attribute.Value

    dbObjs.session.commit()
except (KeyError, AttributeError) as err:
    self.query_failed(err)
```

Update 3:

By having a look at the suggestions in the answers, I settled down for this solution:

In `Creatures`

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key in self.__dict__:
       setattr(self, key, value)
    else:
       raise KeyError(key)
```

In the other method

```
 # Applying object attributes to user attributes
 for attribute in obj.attributes:
     cur_creature[str(attribute.Name)] += attribute.Value
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem does not reside in SQLAlchemy but is due to Python's [descriptors mechanism](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). Every `Column` attribute is a descriptor: this is how SQLAlchemy 'hooks' the attribute retrieval and modification to produce database requests.

Let's try with a simpler example:

```
class Desc(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        print '__get__'
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        print '__set__'

class A(object):
    desc = Desc()

a = A()
a.desc                  # prints '__get__'
a.desc = 2              # prints '__set__'
```

However, if you go through `a` *instance* dictionary and set another value for `'desc'`, you bypass the descriptor protocol (see [Invoking Descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors)):

```
a.__dict__['desc'] = 0  # Does not print anything !
```

Here, we just created a new *instance* attribute called `'desc'` with a value of 0. The `Desc.__set__` method was never called, and in your case SQLAlchemy wouldn't get a chance to 'catch' the assignment.

The solution is to use [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr), which is exactly equivalent to writing `a.desc`:

```
setattr(a, 'desc', 1)   # Prints '__set__'
```

Comment: Before marking this as an answer, I have 1 further question and 1 remark:

1) Why doesn't the second call "cur_creature.Health  = 100" call __set__ after I modified the attribute through the dictionary

2) 'setattr()' does not trigger KeyError if I specify an attribute that is not already in the class

Comment: 1) Once you define an *instance* attribute through `__dict__` it hides the *class* attributes due to Python's attribute lookup rules

Comment: 2) `setattr(obj, 'a', 0)` is equivalent to `obj.a = 0` so no, it won't raise a `KeyError`. You can however use [`hasattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) to check for attribute existence.

Comment: @@icecrime Done. Thanks, it helped me to reach my final solution and clarified many things.

Comment: @icecrime, thanks! Five hours of searching for a solution to this, yours was the only one that addressed my actual issue and pointed me toward a solution.

Comment: Alas, this does not work for me. I am doing it inside a `replace(temp)` function of the class, so that any attributes of temp (same class as self) should be used to update self. Am I missing something?!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `__dict__`. Use `getattr` and `setattr` to modify attributes by name:

```
for attribute in obj.attributes:
    setattr(cur_creature,str(attribute.Name), getattr(cur_creature,str(attribute.Name)) + attribute.Value)
```

More info:

[setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

[getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)