# Flask-SQLAlchemy update record method doesn't work on database

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to generalize the update method of the user table. For example; I want to be able to pass the updated column as a keyword argument. These are the relevant parts of the module.

`update_user()` finds the user by its username and updates its fields by updating the `__dict__` attribute.

```
class UserModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    reputation = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    registration_date = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False)

    @staticmethod
    def update_user(_username, **kwargs):
        user = UserModel.query.filter_by(username=_username).first()
        print(kwargs)
        user.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        print(user.__dict__)
        db.session.commit()
```

Let's assume that I want to change the password of the admin...

```
print(UserModel.get_user('admin'))
UserModel.update_user('admin', password='new_password')
print(UserModel.get_user('admin'))
```

The output looks like this...

```
{'id': 1, 'username': 'admin', 'password': '1234', 'email': 'asd@qwe.com', 'registration_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 1, 19, 58, 35, 216025), 'reputation': 1}
{'password': 'new_password'}
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x000001FEE907F128>, 'id': 1, 'registration_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 1, 19, 58, 35, 216025), 'email': 'asd@qwe.com', 'username': 'admin', 'reputation': 1, 'password': 'new_password'}
{'id': 1, 'username': 'admin', 'password': '1234', 'email': 'asd@qwe.com', 'registration_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 1, 19, 58, 35, 216025), 'reputation': 1}
```

When I print `user.__dict__`, it shows that the password is updated, but it is not reflected to database. That's why when I query the record again, it shows the old password. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem, but lost the elegancy of __dict__.update(kwargs) :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQLAlchemy commit changes to object modified through __dict__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013965/sqlalchemy-commit-changes-to-object-modified-through-dict) suggests using `__dict__` is not a good way to do updates.

You can simulate `dict.update` by iterating over `kwargs`.

```
@staticmethod
def update_user(_username, **kwargs):
    user = UserModel.query.filter_by(username=_username).first()
    print(kwargs)

    for key, value in kwargs.items():  # `kwargs.iteritems()` in Python 2
        setattr(user, key, value) 

    print(user.__dict__)
    db.session.commit()
```