# What is the difference between `vars` and `setattr`?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

> After failing to use vars to change db.Model(flask-sqlalchemy) value I solved it by using `setattr` instead, but after reading doc still don't get the difference between `vars` and `setattr`.

Here is what I have tried

### Failed in `vars`

#### Code

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def set_option_parameters(var, option_keys, options):
    for option_key in options:
        if option_key in option_keys and options[option_key] is not None:
            vars(var)[option_key] = options[option_key]
            # setattr(var, option_key, options[option_key])

class Application(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(20), nullable=False)
    ...
    def __init__(self, options):
        option_keys = set(["name"])
        set_option_parameters(self, option_keys, options)

    def modification(self, options):
        modifiable = set(["name"])
        set_option_parameters(self, modifiable, options)
```

`vars(var)[option_key] = options[option_key]` *works fine in initing a `Application` object* , but failed in `modification`(`name` didn't change).

#### Log/Test

And I tried to print the `application.__dict__` before `db.session.commit()`, it did be modified!

```
application = Application.query.filter_by(id=args["id"]).first()
# args["name"] is not None
app.logger.info(f"Before: {application.__dict__}")
application.modification(args)
app.logger.info(f"After: {application.__dict__}")
db.session.commit()
```

output

```
[2019-02-27 11:22:59,209] INFO in equipmentbaseapplicationhandler: Before:{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f718ac2b588>, 'id': 9, 'name': 'old_name'}
[2019-02-27 11:22:59,209] INFO in equipmentbaseapplicationhandler: After:{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f718ac2b588>, 'id': 9, 'name': 'new_name'}
```

**BUT** When I checked in mysql, it did not work

### Successed in `setattr`

Then I changed to `setattr(var, option_key, options[option_key])` in function `set_option_parameters`.

it works good in both init and modification, and the output of `application.__dict__` is the same!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013965/sqlalchemy-commit-changes-to-object-modified-through-dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) for `vars`:

> Objects such as modules and instances have an updateable **dict** attribute; however, other objects may have write restrictions on their **dict** attributes (for example, classes use a types.MappingProxyType to prevent direct dictionary updates).

Looking through the SQLAlchemy source code (for instance, [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/c9a31767e0d3a15ab45101aca21924cb4434c7b9/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py#L326)), it is a common pattern to return a copy of `some_model.__dict__` when accessed, rather than returning the `__dict__` itself. So you are likely updating a copy rather than the original. Otherwise, it's possible that the dict is getting overwritten by the attributes themselves, even if the dict changes.

`setattrs` is the correct pattern, and is more explicit.